# Convert SQL query to LINQ query not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this situation:

```
select max(id) from OTX group by AccNo
```

I want to convert it into a LINQ query but is not working. I tried this but says that Message = "The member 'XX' has no supported translation to SQL.":

```
var result = from otx in datacTx.OTX
             group otxCf by otxCf.AccNo
             into Client
             select Client.Max().ID;
```

Comment: Is 'XX' the actual name of the member?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var result = from otx in datacTx.OTX
         group otxCf by otxCf.AccNo
         into Client
         select Client.Max(r=>r.id);
```

or if you want the same as

```
select AccNo, max(id) from OTX group by AccNo
```

then try

```
var result = from otx in datacTx.OTX
         group otxCf by otxCf.AccNo
         into Client
         select new { AccNo = Client.Key , MaxValue= Client.Max(r=>r.id) } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from otx in datacTx.OTX
             group otxCf by otxCf.AccNo
             into Client
             select new { MaxId = Client.Max(s => s.ID)};
```